Is there a way to change the speed options in the PlayerView?
I want to change the options for the speeds shown (.25x, .5x, .75x, Normal, 1.25x, 1.5x, and 2x) in videos. So far I've tried adding a speed controller to the ExoPlayer builder but it doesn't do anything. There is no a lot of documentation for how to do this.
I've tried adding a LiveSpeedController but it doesn't look like that's the right direction for this. I also haven't seen anyone posted a similar question to this in StackoverFlow
private val speedController = DefaultLivePlaybackSpeedControl.Builder()
        .setFallbackMaxPlaybackSpeed(1f)
        .setFallbackMinPlaybackSpeed(.5f)
        .build()


Firstly You have to define a ENUM or sealed class depending upon your preference, But I chose ENUM here.
// Since we would need text to be shown on the  Ui Front        
enum class PlaybackSpeedText(val value: String) {
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_POINT_5x("0.5x"),
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_NORMAL("Normal"),
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_1_POINT_25x("1.25x"),
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_1_POINT_5x("1.5x"),
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_1_POINT_75x("1.75x"),
        PLAYBACK_SPEED_2x("2x")
    }

Then you need to have float value for every particular ENUM class like this
const val SPEED_NORMAL = 1.0F;
const val SPEED_POINT_5x = 0.5F;
const val SPEED_1_POINT_25x = 1.25F;
const val SPEED_1_POINT_5x = 1.5F;
const val SPEED_1_POINT_75x = 1.75F;
const val SPEED_2x = 2.0F;

Then depending on how you configured your exoplayer object you need to pass the selected speed like this.
   val param = PlaybackParameters(speed)
   if (exoPlayer != null) exoPlayer!!.playbackParameters = param

Here PlaybackParameters is the Exoplayer internal package class that sets the speed using the above float value.

Additionally, to check the current speed of the media you can use
this.

  if (exoPlayer != null) exoPlayer!!.playbackParameters.speed

